# Which is better, a function with one return statement or multiple ones? [Embedded C]

Tags: c, switch-statement, return, microcontroller

While developing a code for the micro-contoller, I faced these warning that my function has multiple return statements.

I can replace them with single one at the end  of the function, but I thought this is better. Could someone explain to me which is better and why

```
 unsigned char getDays(unsigned char oldDay,unsigned char newDay,unsigned char currentMonth){
  unsigned char xtemp;
    if(oldDay < newDay){    //in the same month
          xtemp = newDay - oldDay ;
                        return xtemp ;
        }
    else{
            switch(currentMonth){   
                case 2:
                case 4:
                case 6:                 
                case 8:         
                case 9:
                case 0x11:
                case 1:
                        xtemp = newDay + 0x31 - oldDay;     
                        return xtemp ;
                break;
                case 3:
                        xtemp = newDay + 0x28-oldDay;
                        return xtemp ;
                        break;
                case 5:         
                case 7:
                case 0x10:
                case 0x12:
                        xtemp = newDay+0x30-oldDay;
                        return xtemp ;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: if `currentMonth` is somthing else than the values in your `switch` you return nothing.

Comment: Also, I hope you are aware that `0x11` is `17` decimal...

Comment: you should add a default section in the switch case. The compiler has recognised that there are values which are not handled.

Comment: i use BCD ...so the values more than 9 i add 0x..

Comment: So you're suggesting that `currentMonth` can have values of  `1` to `9`, `16` (`0x10`), `17` (`0x11`), and `18` (`0x12`)?   Unusual calendar.

Comment: @Peter i use RTC in my project where it gives the values encoded as BCD .... so it's usual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that all paths with a `return` statement calculate a value of `xtemp` and then finish with `return xtemp;`, and there are no loops so the flow is clear, I suggest a single return statement would suffice.

That said, I think the number of return statements is the most minor problem with that code.

Your switch statement has no `default` clause so, if `currentMonth` is not any of the chosen `case` values, the function falls off the end (with no `return` statement at all).   That causes the caller to have undefined behaviour if it uses the return value of your function.   Having a single `return` statement at the end would eliminate that problem, if the code is structured so `xtemp` is always initialised or assigned a value.

I'd also be concerned about readability - a set of magic values, some expressed as decimal and some as hex, increases difficulty for mere mortals to understand the code - which in turn makes it harder to get right.   In fact, my hunch is that - because you have used a hex value in at least one place where a decimal value appears to have been intended - that you have not actually got that code working correctly.

Rather than a `switch`, I'd probably use some carefully constructed `if/else if` statements.

Comment: The OP mentioned they are using BCD (unpacked by the looks of it). Which is quite reasonable for a calendar, if circumstances call for it. Those hex values are not a mistake. I doubt any `if/else` statement will be more readable than a switch in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks alot for your help ... with your help that's the final code i get

```
unsigned char getDays(unsigned char oldDay,unsigned char newDay,unsigned char currentMonth){
    if (oldDay > newDay){
        switch(currentMonth){   
            case 0x3:                                 return newDay + 0x28 - oldDay;
            case 0x5: case 0x7: case 0x10: case 0x12: return newDay + 0x30 - oldDay;
            default:                                  return newDay + 0x31 - oldDay;
        }
    }
    return newDay - oldDay; //in the same month
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the math is correct? `0x11 + 0x30 - 0x25 = 0x1c`. Which is not a number in BCD.